# Confirm-Button event fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So I have a confirm button:

```
<confirm-button class-name="btn-primary" 
                text="Save"
                body="A customer with the same Last Name is already associated with this Company. Do you want to create this customer anyway?"
                action="vm.save(false)"
                place="bottom"></confirm-button>
```

It's a custom directive:

```
.directive('confirmButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            text: '@',
            className: '@',
            action: '&'
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var content = $attrs.body ? '<p>' + $attrs.body + '</p>' : '';
            var place = $attrs.place ? $attrs.place : 'top';

            var rndEleId = 'BtnId' + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);

            var popoverOpts = {
                title: $attrs.title || 'Are you sure?',
                placement: place,
                html: true,
                content: content +
                    '<div class="centered">' +
                    '<button id="yes' + rndEleId + '" name="yes' + rndEleId + '" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" data-result="yes"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes</button>' +
                    '&nbsp;' +
                    '<button id="no' + rndEleId + '" name="no' + rndEleId + '" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-small" data-result="no"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> No</button>' +
                    '</div>'
            };

            $element.popover(popoverOpts)
                .parent()
                .delegate('button',
                    'click',
                    function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var el = $(e.currentTarget);
                        var result = el.data('result');

                        $element.popover('hide');

                        if (result === 'yes') {
                            $scope.$apply($scope.action);
                        }
                    }
                );
        },
        template: '<a href="" class="btn {{className}}">{{text}}</a>'
    };
})
```

I have this button on the page twice: once at the top of the page, and once at the bottom. Regardless of which one you click, when the Yes or No buttons are clicked, they fire twice. This means the Save method in the button Action property is called twice. If you're updating a record, that's not a horrible thing, but if you're creating a record... It's created twice.

I used Chrome's Developer Tools and placed a breakpoint on the `e.preventDefault();` line in the directive, and sure enough, it gets hit twice.

But this ONLY happens if there is more than one of these directives used on the page. If I have just one button (at top or bottom of the page), the `e.preventDefault();` breakpoint only gets hit once. Further, it seems like it's multi-threaded. I put a counter variable in at one point, with the old school theory of "set it to 0, then set it to ++, and check to see if it's now 1. If it's greater than 1, don't do the action. If it equals 1, do the action." And the variable... was created new each time, and thus never incremented past 1.

I'm stymied.

Comment: Not sure if you know, but there's a native implementation for a popover (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#popover)

Comment: It could be easier to find a solution if you will provide a JSFiddle or Plunker with reproduced bug.

Comment: @Alon Eitan - Actually, that's what is in the directive. It's using the popover implementation from Angular, and extending it to be a Confirm dialog.

Comment: @PKD Cool, note that you can implement it using a custom template (It's there in the examples) and you can bind the click events to the buttons using `ngClick`

Comment: Does that same popover implementation exist for Bootstrap 2.3.2? I'm sadly unable at this point to upgrade the bootstrap version in the app.

Answer (score 1):

**You haven't really asked a direct question but it appears that you want to know *why* this is happening.**

It's happening because you are adding a click event listener to the parent of the directive **every time** the directive loads. So when you had 2 of these directives on the same page, you clicked your button and the event was fired twice because there are 2 event listeners registered. Heres where you are registering your event listener using the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method:

```
$element.popover(popoverOpts)
  .parent()
  .delegate('button',
    'click',
      function(e) {
        ...
```

First of all you need to make sure that you **clean up after yourself** and unbind your event listener when your directive get's destroyed (check out [life-cycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) in the documentation). Here is a quick example of how you can unbind your event listener when your directive get's destroyed:

```
// ...

// register your popover here
$element.popover(popoverOpts);

// reference your parent
var parent = $element.parent();

// reference your click function
var handleClick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var el = $(e.currentTarget);
    var result = el.data('result');

    $element.popover('hide');

    if (result === 'yes') {
        $scope.$apply($scope.action);
    }
}

// register your event listener
parent.on('click', handleClick);

// when your directive get's destroyed you need to unbind the `handleClick` function
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(e) {
    parent.off('click', handleClick);
});

// ...
```

To solve your issue you will need to make sure that you are registering your event listeners to suit your needs. You can read more about event listeners [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Although to be honest, looking at your code, you should give [`ui-bootstrap`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) a try.

Comment: "Why" was the exact thing I was hoping to have answered. Also, I'm using Bootstrap, but 2.3.2 (there's a very long, drawn out, story as to why the site isn't on the latest version, but that'd take too long to get into) doesn't deal with things in a pleasant way.

Comment: That's fine, there is nothing wrong with not using ui-bootstrap, just make sure you clean up your listeners otherwise you'll have memory leaks all over the shop.

Comment: I noticed in your code that you lose the "popoverOpts"... How do the options make it into your Popover?

Comment: You still need to pass in your popoverOpts, you can do this separately or chain it in the middle of `var parent = $element.popover(popoverOpts)parent();` - I've updated my answer above to include that part